# Use python regex to replace dataframe column values with decimal part of string

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column df['gravidityAndParity'] that contains string values like so:

```
0      g4p3
1      g2p0
2      g7p2
3      g2p0
4      g7p6
```

The number after 'g' is the gravidity and the number after 'p' is the parity. I am trying to split this column into two columns: df['gravidity'] and df['parity]

So the output I am after is:

```py
print(df['gravidity'])
```

```
0      4
1      2
2      7
3      2
4      7
```

```py
print(df['parity])
```

```
0      3
1      0
2      2
3      0
4      6
```

I defined a function using regex to do this, but the function is not working correctly.

Here is my code so far:

```py
import regex as re 
  
# Function to clean the names
def Split_gravidity_parity(gravidityAndParity):
    match_gravidity = re.search('g(\d+)', gravidityAndParity)
    if match_gravidity:
        df['gravidity']= match_gravidity.group(1)
        
    match_parity = re.search('p(\d+)', gravidityAndParity)
    if match_parity:
        df['parity']= match_parity.group(1)
```

Applying the function to the column:

```py
df['gravidityAndParity'].apply(Split_gravidity_parity)

print(df['gravidity'])
```

```
0      4
1      4
2      4
3      4
4      4
```

```py
print(df['parity'])
```

```
0      3
1      3
2      3
3      3
4      3
```

The function seems to be partially working, as it only seems to be applied to the first value in the column 'g4p3'.

Any help with how I can implement this regex function correctly to all values in the column and output the results in two new columns 'gravidity' and 'parity'?

Comment: Side question: do you really need the PyPi regex library here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `re` with `Series.str.extract`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'gravidityAndParity':['g4p3','g2p0','g7p2','g2p0','g7p6']})
df[['gravity','parity']] = df['gravidityAndParity'].str.extract(r'g(\d+)p(\d+)')
# => >>> df
#       gravidityAndParity gravity parity
#     0               g4p3       4      3
#     1               g2p0       2      0
#     2               g7p2       7      2
#     3               g2p0       2      0
#     4               g7p6       7      6
```

The `g(\d+)p(\d+)` pattern captures one or more digits after `g` into Group 1 (the "gravity" column) and the matches `p` and then captures one or more digits into Group 2 (the "parity" column).